# R won't execute code correctly

Tags: r

Here's my code:

```
dx <- c(1, 0.1)
xR <- vector("list", length(dx))
for (i in 1:2) {
 xR[[i]] <- seq(from=0, to=3, by=dx[i])}
```

I keep getting:

```
> xR
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL
```

instead of:

```
[[1]]
[1] 0 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0 1.1     
    1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8
[20] 1.9 2.0 2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.7 2.8 2.9 3.0
```

I use Rstudio Version 1.1.419, R 3.4.2

Comment: You don't describe what the code is intended to do, so it's impossible to determine precisely what the question is, but this single line will reproduce your output: `lapply(dx, seq, from=0, to=3)`

Comment: Your code works fine when I run it.

Answer (score 0):

`xR` gives me a null value when I execute it before executing your for loop. After executing your for loop, I indeed obtain the values that you want (0 to 3 sequenced by 1, and 0.0 to 3.0 sequenced by 0.1)

```
dx <- c(1, 0.1)
xR <- vector("list", length(dx))
for (i in 1:2) {
  xR[[i]] <- seq(from=0, to=3, by=dx[i])}
xR
```

Which outputs:

```
[[1]]
[1] 0 1 2 3

[[2]]
 [1] 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9 2.0 2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.7 2.8
[30] 2.9 3.0
```